# jQuery selector vs filter()

Tags: jquery, performance

Given the following markup

```
<ul class="list">
    <li>first item</li>
    ​<li class="item">second item</li>
    <li>third item</li>
</ul>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Which one these 2 expressions is better to select the second li?

```
$("ul li.item")
```

or

```
$("ul li").filter(".item")
```

This is not a very good example because it's too simple (I know I could be doing `$(".item")`, but in general, should I be using complex selectors or the filter function?

**EDIT**: If the first is more efficient, when is it appropriate / best to use the filter function?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The first is faster:

```
$("ul li.item")
```

This is true simply because it's equivalent, but isn't running the selector engine (Sizzle) twice to get there.

*For your edit:* You use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)...well, when you need to filter the current set, or when you need a complex filter.  For example if you wanted to chain but not select the set again:

```
$("ul li").addClass('everyItem').filter('.item').fadeOut();
```

Or a complex filter:

```
$("ul li").filter(function() {
  return $.data(this, 'hasSomething');
}).fadeOut();
```

There are *many* uses of filter, it really depends on the situation as to what fits best.  As pertains to your question though, `$(selector).filter(selector)`...I can't think of a case where you'd want this over a single selector if it's at all possible.  The only case off the top of my head you *can't* do that is a complex [`:has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) and [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) wrapping.