# JQuery: Find (the index of) a row with a specific data attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to append a string, myoutput, right after a specific row in a table similar to this one:

```
<table>
<tr data-my_id='1'> <td> content </td> </tr>
<tr data-my_id='2' data-my_other_id='1' > <td> content </td> </tr>
<tr data-my_id='3' data-my_other_id='2' > <td> content </td> </tr>
</table>
```

So let's say I want to append my output string after the tr with `data-my_other_id='2'`
(note that in my code, `my_other_id = 2` already )

I am trying to accomplish it doing this:

```
var want = $("tr").find("[data-my_other_id='" + my_other_id + "']").index();
```

after finding the index, I want to append my output strhing to this row...

```
$(want).insertAfter(...?);
```

Also... I noticed whenever I do

```
alert( want = $("tr").find("[data-my_other_id='" + my_other_id + "']").length)
```

I get 0 ...

Help please and let me know if my question is not clear enough so I can explain better.

Comment: There are 2 problems.. you are using "find" which is for descendants of tr.  Also your use of index is wrong, it returns an integer. see my answer below

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to update the content rather than append, but it doesn't really change anything.  I don't think you want to use find() that way.  Try something like:

```
var $row = $('tr[data-my_other_id="' + id + '"]');
// should be the index of the tr in the <table>
// this may not be a good idea though - what if you add a header row later?
var index = row.index() + 1; // if you want 1-based indices
$row.find("td").text("I am row #" + index);
```

Comment: How do I do this to access a row in a second (non selected) datatable?  Question here:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/45420939/1735836

Answer (score 2):

This is because find will no search siblings, only children. Try attaching your search to table.

html:

```
<table>
<tr data-my_id='1'> <td> content </td> </tr>
<tr data-my_id='2' data-my_other_id='1' > <td> content </td> </tr>
<tr data-my_id='3' data-my_other_id='2' > <td> content </td> </tr>
</table>​
```

js:

```
var my_other_id = 2;
alert( $("table").find("[data-my_other_id='" + my_other_id + "']").length);​
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gDb3A/

Comment: Or use .filter(), as in $("tr").filter("[data-my_other_id= ... etc.

Comment: Or $("tr[data-my_other_id='" + my_other_id + "']")

Comment: Thanks for replying. For some reason using find or filter wasn't working for me. @Benoir 's answer worked just fine.

Comment: $("table").find("[data-my_other_id='" + my_other_id + "']") returns jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[0].  Question here:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/45420939/1735836

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use the find method since the data attribute is on the tr itself.  Also your use of index is not going to work.  Try the following instead.

```
$("tr[data-my_other_id='" + my_other_id + "']").insertAfter(...?);
```

Comment: Thanks - I don't think you can pick 2 answers

Answer (score 1):

`find` looks for descendents. A `TR` can not be a descendent of itself.

Try using `filter()`

```
$("tr").filter("[data-my_other_id='" + my_other_id + "']").index();
```

Comment: I would avoid using filter, since it will first select all tr's

Comment: @Justin, it will do it anyways

Comment: @Alexander - not if you do the following $("tr[data-my_other_id='" + my_other_id + "']")

Comment: @Justin  JQuery uses filter internally to parse your selector...look in jQuery source... not much difference if you call it or jQuery calls it

Comment: @charlietfl it has to run the selector sizzle engine twice -> see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3461374/jquery-selector-vs-filter

Comment: @Justin  for class perhaps... attribute is not same

Comment: @charlietfl sizzle supports selecting by attribute though

Comment: @JustinBicknell How do I do this in a different table?  Question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45420939/1735836

Answer (score 0):

Find in the specific table so it will be faster, you can use this method.

Js:

```
$('any-button').click(function(){
    var id = 23;
    var $row = $('.your-class tbody tr[data-id="' + id + '"]');
    $row.remove();
});
```

Html

```
<table class="table table-striped your-class">
        <thead>
        <tr>...<tr/>
       </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr data-id="23">Some text</tr>
       <tr data-id="43">Some text</tr>
       <tr data-id="43">Some text</tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```