# How can I change my code into clickable row from input checkbox row in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table and the data in this table is from database. I want to click this row and transfer it to other table. I can transfer this row using input checkbox. I'd realize that it will be easy and convenient to transfer the rows by just clicking it without checkbox. I have a hard time converting it to a clickable instead of checkbox.

I tried using this code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#table1 tbody tr" ).on( "click", function( event ) {
        var product = $(this).attr('data-product');
        var price = $(this).attr('data-price');
        var barcode = $(this).attr('data-barcode');
        var unit = $(this).attr('data-unt');
        var qty = prompt("Enter number of items",1);
        var total = qty*price;

        $('#tableData').append("<tr><td>"+barcode+"</td><td>"+product+"</td><td>₱"+price+"</td><td>"+unit+"</td><td>"+qty+"</td><td>₱"+total+"</td><tr>");});
```

This is my jquery that I wanted to convert into clickable code.

```
    function add(){
         $('input:checked[name=tab1]').each(function() {
         var product = $(this).attr('data-product');
         var price = $(this).attr('data-price');
         var barcode = $(this).attr('data-barcode');
         var unit = $(this).attr('data-unt');
         var qty = prompt("Enter number of items",1);
         var total = qty*price;

         $('#tableData').append("<tr><td>"+barcode+"</td><td>"+product+"</td><td>₱"+price+"</td><td>"+unit+"</td><td>"+qty+"</td><td>₱"+total+"</td><tr>"); });}
```

My PHP code.

```
<?php
include('server/connection.php');

if (isset($_POST['products'])){

    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['products']);
    $num = 1;
    $show   = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_name LIKE '$name%' ";
    $query  = mysqli_query($db,$show);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($query)>0){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
            $total = $num*$row['sell_price'];
            echo "<tr id='sas'><td>".$row['id']."</td><td>".$row['product_name']."</td>";
            echo "<td>₱".$row['sell_price']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['unit']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['quantity']."</td>";
            echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='tab1' data-barcode='".$row['id']."' data-product='".$row['product_name']."' data-price='".$row['sell_price']."' data-unt='".$row['unit']."' data-qty='".$num."' data-total='".$total."'/></td></tr>";
        }
    }
    else{
        echo "<td></td><td>No Products found!</td><td></td>";
    }
}
```

My Table

```
<table id="table1">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <td>Barcode</td>
         <td>Product Name</td>
         <td>Price</td>
         <td>Unit</td>
         <td>Stocks</td>
         <td>Action</td>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody id="products">
   </tbody>
</table>
<table id="table2">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Barcode</th>
         <th>Description</th>
         <th>Price</th>
         <th>Unit</th>
         <th>Qty</th>
         <th>Sub.Total</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody id="tableData">
   </tbody>
</table>
```

I expect by just clicking the row it will automatically transfer to the table2 with a dialog box using prompt that will ask for quantity of a product then it will be printed to the second table along with the entire row.

This is my UI with css. [image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right way, just fix JS selectors using $(this) and formating  the price...

```js
$("#table1 .js-add").on("click", function() {
    var target = $(this);
    var product = target.attr('data-product');
    var price = target.attr('data-price');
    var barcode = target.attr('data-barcode');
    var unit = target.attr('data-unt');
    var qty = prompt("Enter number of items", 1);
    var total = qty * price;
       
    $('#tableData').append("<tr><td>" + barcode + "</td><td>" + product + "</td><td>" + price + "</td><td>" + unit + "</td><td>" + qty + "</td><td>" + total.toFixed(2) + "</td><tr>");
  });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="table1" class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Barcode</th>
      <th>Product Name</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Unit</th>
      <th>Stocks</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="products">
    <tr>
      <td>123412</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>12.99</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>
        <input name='tab1' type="checkbox" class='js-add' data-barcode="123412" data-product="Test" data-price="12.99" data-unt="1"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<table id="table2" class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Barcode</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Unit</th>
      <th>Qty</th>
      <th>Sub.Total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tableData">
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I got a problem with my jquery it doesnt load. When I copy the jquery and paste it on the console its working but it my script link it doesnt. I wondering how this jquery doesnt load.

Comment: I cant get  the .js-add class because in my project its outside of the the page. It will show only when I search in the search box. So the listener cant catch the tag.

Comment: no make sense '-' ... your problem is with your environment not with code. My code work well in snippet, so, retrieve the logic and apply to your environment.

Comment: If your code can't catch the listener, put the click trigger after you search in your box... Or change the logic to watch the document changes, something like: `$('body').on('click', '.js-add', function() { /* the same logic as above... */ });`

Comment: Yes I believe I got a problem with my environment. Thats why It does not work. But I'd use your suggested code. The problem now is I cant make it work . Im still searching why It didnt work. By the way, big thanks with you.

Comment: Its working now. I'd use your suggested code. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `event.target` instead of `this` in the function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#table1 tbody tr" ).on( "click", function( event ) {
        var target = event.target;
        var product = target.attr('data-product');
        var price = target.attr('data-price');
        var barcode = target.attr('data-barcode');
        var unit = target.attr('data-unt');
        var qty = prompt("Enter number of items",1);
        var total = qty*price;

        $('#tableData').append("<tr><td>"+barcode+"</td><td>"+product+"</td><td>₱"+price+"</td><td>"+unit+"</td><td>"+qty+"</td><td>₱"+total+"</td><tr>");});
```

Comment: When I click the row nothing happens.

Comment: My php file is different in my main page. Is it matters? I cant transfer the row even if I already loaded my js. I'd tried putting the jquery in the console and its working .

Answer (score -1):

On tr click event, you are using data-product and other selectors. data-product is not defined for tr. You have to add data-product attribute for each row. You can refer this - [JQuery: Find (the index of) a row with a specific data attribute value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14166557/jquery-find-the-index-of-a-row-with-a-specific-data-attribute-value)