# When to use filter() versus : in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I'm reviewing some JavaScript/jQuery fundamentals and am curious over the use of `filter()` and the `:`

What's the difference between them?

Why do these lines of code work:

```
$("li").filter(":even").css("background-color", "red"); 
$("li:even").css("background-color", "red"); 
$("p").filter(".intro").css("color", "green");
```

but something like these won't?

```
$("li").filter("even").css("background-color", "red");
$("p:.intro").css("color", "green");
```

So when would you use `filter()` versus `:`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery selector vs filter()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3461374/jquery-selector-vs-filter)

Comment: As for your _"non-working"_ examples, 1) `.filter('even')` will attempt to filter the list to `<even>` elements. These don't exist and certainly wouldn't also be `<li>` elements. 2) jQuery does not have a selector filter (ie the `:something` style) for classes. The equivalent would simply be `p.intro`

Comment: @Phil: I recommend posting that as an answer instead, as the duplicate doesn't contain the same errors that are pertinent to this question and there's probably an opportunity for you to highlight the differences more clearly *with these errors in mind*.

Comment: @BoltClock done 

Comment: @BoltClock wow, downvotes already. Maybe not such a good idea 

Comment: @Phil: Oops. Have an upvote for the trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What's the difference between them?

I think this is best answered in [jQuery selector vs filter()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3461374/jquery-selector-vs-filter) but to summarise...

The first uses jQuery's selector engine ([Sizzle](https://sizzlejs.com/)) only once to produce a jQuery object representing a collection of elements.

The latter using `.filter()` does the same as above but then applies the selector engine again to filter those results. As can be seen in the linked post, `.filter()` has uses other than just a selector-string.

Sizzle provides selection features roughly equivalent to the CSS 3 selectors you can use in `document.querySelector()` but with some extras, most of which fall under the *filter* category; that is those following a colon character.

---

> Why do these lines of code work
>   ...
>   but something like these won't?

Let's look at what you're asking of the selector...

```
$("li").filter(":even")
$("li:even")
```

These are equivalent (with the exception of *when* they do things) but this is one of those extra *features* in the Sizzle library; positional filters like `:first`, `:odd` and of course, `:even`.

Now this...

```
$("li").filter("even")
```

is first asking for all `<li>` elements then it attempts to filter that by the `"even"` selector string. This is an element selector so you're asking for all the `<li>` elements that are also `<even>` elements. This obviously is going to result in an empty list.

---

```
$("p").filter(".intro")
```

This gets all `<p>` tags then filtered down to those with the `"intro"` class. The dot (class) selector is a standard CSS 3 selector.

```
$("p:.intro")
```

There is no special dot-selector filter. The standard dot-selector can be combined with an element selector though, producing

```
$('p.intro')
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, Phil! I selected and upvoted your answer, sorry I don't have enough reputation for it to show.